# Publish Function App to azure zipdeploy failed with HTTP status code Unauthorized

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I was able to publish my Function from Visual Studio 2 weeks ago. I made a minor change went to publish and received this error.

```
The attempt to publish the ZIP file through https://xxxxxxxxxxx.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy failed with HTTP status code Unauthorized.
```

Any ideas, I know the 2022 VS was upgraded to a new version last week.

Comment: Did you try enabling Basic Authentication in function app?

Answer (score 5):

- ***Remove the existing publish profile***.

[image]

- Create a ***new publish profile*** and deploy the function app again.
- Enable the **Basic Authentication** in `Azure Portal=>Function App=>Settings=>Configuration=>General Settings` before deploying the function:

[image]

- I have created and deployed a Http Triggered function to Azure.

**Application Settings of my function app:**

[image]

- Created a publish profile to Zip Deploy the function to .NET Azure function app.

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]